# Using different markup for views last item

Tags: 7, views, theming

I need to use different markup for last item displayed by views. Using first last css item does not do the job for me. I assume I would need custom php template probably views-view-fields.tpl.php. What would be the way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

- Find template file that adds "last" class
- Override it in your custom theme
- Expand if responsible for "last" class, to make it contain all element's markup
- in if block write markup for last element, in else block - for all other elements.

Comment: Hi I am not exactly sure what you mean. The views template responsible for first/last class should be views-view-fields.tpl.php but it think it would need some additional php code or?